# awk merge columns from multiple files, append different values and remove same values

Tags: awk, merge, duplicates

I have two files:

```
try7.txt
a   32145
b   eioue
c   32654895
d   bdefgac
e   kkloi
f   6549465
g   test123452
h   est0124358

try8.txt
a   32145562
b   eioueddf
c   32654
d   bdefgac
e   kkloi
f   6549465dww
g   test123
h   est0124358df
i   63574968fd
j   dfsdfcd5
```

desired output:

```
a  32145562      32145
b  eioueddf      eioue
c  32654         32654895
d  bdefgac       0
e  kkloi         0
f  6549465dww    6549465
g  test123       test123452
h  est0124358df  est0124358
i  63574968fd    0
j  dfsdfcd5      0
```

actual output:

```
a  32145562      32145
b  eioueddf      eioue
c  32654         32654895
d  bdefgac       bdefgac
e  kkloi         kkloi
f  6549465dww    6549465
g  test123       test123452
h  est0124358df  est0124358
i  63574968fd    0
j  dfsdfcd5      0
```

The codes I found:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
    {if($1 in a){print $0,a[$1];delete a[$1]}
        else print $0,"0"}
    END{for(x in a)print x,"0",a[x]}' try7.txt try8.txt|sort -n|column -t
```

How do I modify these codes to meet my requirement?

Comment: You want to print both columns if they differ but zero for the second column if they are the same?

Comment: yes, so that I can draw the rows with the same names after.

Comment: Another question is these codes are for two files, how do I do the same thing for like 5 or more files?

Comment: Can you guarantee that a specific file is the longest? You just want each file added as a column with duplicate columns replaced with `0`? Using `join` on each file in turn might be the simplest way to merge them all then awk can fix the duplicate columns easily.

Comment: NO, I can't. I don't know which file is the longest. That might be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit lengthy

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} 
     ($1 in a) && a[$1] != $2{print $1,$2,a[$1]} 
     ($1 in a) && a[$1] == $2 {print $1, $2,"0"} 
     !($1 in a ){print $1, $2, 0}'  try7 try8
```

Will give an output as

```
a  32145562 32145
b eioueddf eioue
c 32654 32654895
d bdefgac 0
e kkloi 0
f 6549465dww 6549465
g test123 test123452
h est0124358df est0124358
i 63574968fd 0
j dfsdfcd5 0
```

Comment: Thank you, nu11p01n73R. Works as I desired but how do I do multiple files?

Comment: @Gray if its based on the first file, the awk should work fine just by giving multiple files as input. But the output will only be based on lines in the first file

Comment: I tried using multiple inputs but the output was like cycling, i.e. a b c d e f g h i j a b c d e f g ...

Comment: @Gray It would be bit difficult but will try out anyways

Comment: @Gray when you give multiple files as input, which file contents are you expecting as the first 2 columns?

Comment: any file I think. Does it matter?

Comment: Yeah it matters, if its based on the contents of the first file, it would be easy. But difficult otherwise. See in your expected result the output is based on contents of second file

Comment: OK. Do I have to know which file is longest and make that file as the base? I don't know the length of each file. If it's not the case, let's just use the first file to make it simple.